Having trouble with my while loop being infinite for this bash script
I am just trying to prompt for the username and password and have the while loop end after three incorrect tries. I think that it has something to do with the way I incremented the count. My code returns the "please enter a username and a password portion and then goes into an infinite loop.
#!/bin/bash
myusername="cloud_user"
mypassword="userisawesome"
count=0

echo "Enter Username: "

read username



echo "Enter Password: "

read password

while [ $count -lt 3 ]
 do
  if [ -z "$username" ] || [ -z "$password" ]; then
      echo "Please enter a username and password"
      count=$count+1
  elif [["$username"= "$myusername" && "$password"= "$mypassword"]]; then
  echo "$HOME $TERM"
  else
      count=$count+1
  fi
 done


count=$count+1 doesn't do what you think it does; enable debug mode (set -xv) or add typeset -p count (after the count=$count+1) to see what's being saved in count; a couple alternatives for incrementing count: count=$((count+1)) or ((count++))

Add before your while loop declare -i count to make count=$count+1 work. See help declare.

You can use for count in 0 1 2 or for count in {0..2}

The code you posted will just output syntax errors, it won't do what you say it does. Please run your code through http://shellcheck.net and then post a [mcve] with code that does demonstrate the problem you're asking for help to solve.

As markp-fuso said, your lines count=$count+1 is the problem.
Written like that, it will simply concatenate the string stored in count with the string +1.
Therefore, your count value will be 0+1, then 0+1+1, 0+1+1+1, ...
You have 2 choices:

you change the while loop with for count in {0..2}, and you don't have to update the count value yourself;
you use the arithmetic evaluation in BASH, by replacing your lines count=$count+1 with count=((count+1)), or even better: ((count++)).


Besides the problem with count increment as was told in the comments and the previous answer, the are more bug in your code.
You read username and password outside the loop, so there are no three attempts.
You do not exit the loop when correct username/password are entered.
Erratic spaces in equality checks.
Overcomplicated logic.
The script that checks for username/password no more than 3 times may be like:
myusername="cloud_user"
mypassword="userisawesome"

for count in {1..3}
do
    read -p "Username: " username
    read -p "Password: " password    #you can use -s to have invisible input 
    if [[ "$username" = "$myusername" && "$password" = "$mypassword" ]]
    then
       echo "$HOME $TERM"
       exit 0
    fi
done
exit 1    #you can add error message before this line.


if [["$username"="$myusername" && "$password"="$mypassword"]] contains several syntax errors. Spaces after [[, before ]], and around = are not optional.

@tjm3772 My bad fixed.
